# Bash completion not working for 'aws cli' after installed via brew

Tags: bash, autocomplete, homebrew, amazon-s3

After I use `brew` to install aws cli, here is the message form `brew`:

```
==> awscli
The "examples" directory has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/awscli/examples

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completions and functions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

However the completion does not seems to work. I have even started a new shell, but when I do `aws s3<TAB>` all I see is a list of local files.

EDIT:

```
$ complete -p aws
bash: complete: aws: no completion specification
```

Comment: Add output of `complete -p aws` to your question.

Comment: Done. Output is added to the question.